# Problema com execução de animação em CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animations

Fiz uma animação em CSS, mas parou de funcionar. Aonde esta o erro?

**HTML/CSS**

```css
#loading {
 background-color: #0e5077;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
 margin-top: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

#loading-center {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#loading-center-absolute {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#object_one {
 left: 55px;
 top: 55px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
#object_two {
 left: 45px;
 top: 45px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
#object_three {
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
 animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
#object_four {
 left: 25px;
 top: 25px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.object {
 -moz-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 position: absolute;
 border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 border-left: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 -webkit-animation: animate 2s infinite;
 animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
 <div id="loading-center-absolute">
                <div class="object" id="object_one"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_two"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_three"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_four"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas não tinha que ter um **keyframes** aí não??

Comment: Eita, é verdade, eu estava passando para uma outra página e acabei não copiando essa parte do código. Falta de atenção minha.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você tenha esquecido de adicionar a regra "@keyframes" para executar sua animação, conforme fiz abaixo. Para execução linear, sem pausas entre início e término da animação, adicione "linear" à propriedade "animation".

```css
#loading {
 background-color: #0e5077;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
 margin-top: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

#loading-center {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#loading-center-absolute {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#object_one {
 left: 55px;
 top: 55px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
#object_two {
 left: 45px;
 top: 45px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
#object_three {
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
 animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
#object_four {
 left: 25px;
 top: 25px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.object {
 -moz-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 position: absolute;
 border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 border-left: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 -webkit-animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
 animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
 from {
     transform: rotate(0deg)
 }
 to {
     transform: rotate(360deg)
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
 <div id="loading-center-absolute">
                <div class="object" id="object_one"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_two"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_three"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_four"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#loading {
 background-color: #0e5077;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
 margin-top: 0px;
 top: 0px;
}

#loading-center {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#loading-center-absolute {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#object_one {
 left: 55px;
 top: 55px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
#object_two {
 left: 45px;
 top: 45px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
#object_three {
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
 animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
#object_four {
 left: 25px;
 top: 25px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.object {
 -moz-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 position: absolute;
 border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
 border-left: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
 animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
 <div id="loading-center-absolute">
                <div class="object" id="object_one"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_two"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_three"></div>
                <div class="object" id="object_four"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```